# How to call asyncio functions inside flask application in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-multithreading

I have a flask application that receives the request and trying to take a screenshot from the given URL which is done with asyncio function.

What I have done is ,

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from flask import Flask
import base64
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify, request
import jwt
async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=True)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(target)
    await page.screenshot({'path': '/tmp/screen.png', 'fullPage': True})
    await browser.close()
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/heatMapDbConfigSave', methods=['POST'])
def notify():
    token, target,id = map(
            request.form.get, ('token', 'target','id'))
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main(target))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', port=5002, debug=True)
```

The problem I have faced is, getting error **RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-2'.** .I have googled and gone through previous posts. None helped and not pointed a clear solution.

What was the solution to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like below

```
from flask import Blueprint
import asyncio

health_check = Blueprint('health_check', __name__)


async def first():
    await asyncio.sleep(20)
    return 'first'

async def second():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    return 'second'

async def third():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    return 'third'

def ordinary_generator():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    for future in asyncio.as_completed([first(), second(), third()]):
        print('reached')
        yield loop.run_until_complete(future)

@health_check.route('', methods=['GET'])
def healthcheck():
    """
    Retrieves the health of the service.
    """
    for element in ordinary_generator():
        print(element)
    return "Health check passed"
```

Blueprints are not required, but just used them. You have to register the blueprint in the main app file like below

```
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(health_check, url_prefix='/api/v1/healthcheck')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```